# Update Tables with same structure but different database at once

Tags: php, mysql

Good day all,

I have currently developed a school management solution that lets schools subscribe annually using PHP/Mysql. To sign up a school, I usually create a database for each school but they all use thesame code base. However, I realised that I would encounter a serious maintenance issue when my subscription base increase in event I need to update the database.

Please, is there any way to update all databases at once? For instance, if I need to add a field to a table 'mytable' in all the databases (since all databases are thesame), is there an sql query to update all 'mytables' in all the databases of the schools subscribed on my platform?

Thanks for your responses.
From a Troubled start up CEO

Comment: Your best bet is just to use the same query you use to update your first or master DB to update the others, just change the DB name.

Comment: I don't know if there is such a tool, but I think there isn't. So you will need to write a script that will alter all DBs. You can use the `information_schema` database (table `SCHEMATA`) to get all DB names on the server and alter all DBs in a loop. But I would consider to change the design and use only one DB for all schools.

Comment: as Paul suggested, best to change your design now - but if you don't want to you can just iterate over you db names and prepend to your table name.  you can use one connection and update all the databases without too much trouble.

Comment: You would probably want to design that into having one database, and normalize your data accordingly to fit your logic. It makes no sense to split everything up, unless you have a crazy big system where you will need distributor servers and duplicate data across multiple databases. To need that, we're talking massive data like Facebook etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I had thought that using one database was heavy. There are 2 things then: change the design or looping. Thanks a lot you guys. Very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can put your connections to databases in an array and then loop with something like this:

```
$dbs = array();
$db1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, 
$password); 
$db2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, 
$password); 
$dbs[]=$db1;
$dbs[]=$db2;

foreach($dbs as $db){
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE $table ADD 
$column VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL",$db);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_connect` is deprecated and should not be used by any modern application.  in fact *cannot* be used on php 7+

Comment: Yes you are right, he shoud change it to the one already in his or her application.This is only to demonstrate the idea of creating the connections, add them to array and loop to execute the query in multiple databases.This code even missing variables because its a dummy code.

Comment: you don't even need to create multiple connections... what's the point?

Comment: @billynoah You need to read the question if you want to know the point.

Comment: i read the answer, you don't need multiple db connections to update multiple database.  you are suggesting to use deprecated function which is insecure.  on top of that you are creating multiple db connections for no reason.  -1

Comment: Most probably in most cases you need to

Comment: This is to demonstrate an abstract idea for an existing system. Again please read the question.

Comment: @billynoah If you insist you can edit my answer and I will accept it or you can post your own answer.

Comment: @billynoah if the same parameters are passed  a new connection will not be established but php will use the old one unless you pass true at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.